# How can I make WPML for wordpress NOT translate posts?

Tags: wordpress

I have a site with wpml installed, and a lot of the contents, such as pages and custom content types, will be in several languages. However, the website has a blog, and this will be in english only.

The problem is that I have a blog widget in the footer, and when a language other than english is active, the widget does not return any posts.

I've looked everywhere in the WPML config area and cannot seem to find where to make posts "language-agnostic"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to WPML->Languages.

There, look for the option of which blog posts to display. If you choose to display posts with translations (if exists) or in the default language, you should get what you're asking for.